# How do I write this as a Lambda / Stream / Filter?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to lambdas and filtering streams and stuff in Java 8. I'm having a very hard time with the syntax of converting this to a Java 8 style. Not even convinced it's possible.

```
private List<RecordWrapperDto>filterRecordWrapperDtos(List<RecordWrapperDto> recordWrapperDtos){
    List<RecordWrapperDto> filteredRecordWrapperDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    Long recordId = null;

    for(RecordWrapperDto rwDto : recordWrapperDtos) {
        if(rwDto.getRecordWrapperId() != null && (recordId == null || recordId.equals(rwDto.getRecordId()))) {
            filteredRecordWrapperDtos.add(rwDto);
            recordId = rwDto.getRecordId();
        }
    }
    return filteredRecordWrapperDtos;
}
```

Here is one of my attempts (wrong of course):

```
if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(recordWrapperDtos)) {
        filteredRecordWrapperDtos = recordWrapperDtos.stream().filter(c -> {
            return (c.getRecordWrapperId() != null && (recordId == null || recordId.equals(c.getRecordId())));
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Tho me a bone? One of the problems seems to be that there's state maintained between each loop. Is it even possible to do that? Also in each example I've see, if you had more than one parameter, e.g. `(a,b) -> { stuff }`, it was the same type where "a" was one item and "b" was the next item in the collection... what if it's not? Can I use that to pass something in?  If so, I'm not finding examples.

Comment: you test `rwDto.getRecordWrapperId() != null` but you never use it. shouldn't you? (because it looks like you take the first item id, and then take all those that have the same record id)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: You've correctly identified the problem: having to preserve state during the processing makes using streams difficult and impractical. The way I read your code, you're trying to make sure that only one record is stored for each value of `recordId`. Couldn't you just rephrase your solution to build a map?

Comment: @RomanC I disagree, his question is very confined, he wants to convert a method into Lambda syntax. He shows us the (short) method as well as his attempt.

Comment: As for the types of multiple parameters, each of them is inferred separately, so they can be different, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @njzk2 The null check rwDto.getRecordWrapperId() != null is a conditional requirement. This ID has to exist in order for us to have the value in our result list.

Comment: @biziclop A map? Can you elaborate? The result should be a List.

Comment: This task is not well suited for Streams because you are creating a link between each element: you add the first record, then you add the record which had the previous `recordId`, and so until the end. Your for loop is really easier to read.

Comment: Who the heck is down voting? Seems like a pretty good question if the answer turns out to be, "You can't do that. No state between loops using this method."

Comment: @user447607 I didn't downvote but it would be useful if you told us what exactly the code is supposed to do.

Comment: @biziclop If I knew exactly, I couldn't tell you because of the NDA. It's been "sanitized" of course.  I was just trying to fix a minor Sonar issue and ran into this syntax "learning experience" with Streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, you can simplify you algorithm to this:

- take the first item that has a `getRecordWrapperId` not null
- take the record id
- filter the stream according to this record id

Like this:

```
Long recordId = recordWrapperDtos
         .stream()
         .filter(c -> c.getRecordWrapperId() != null)
         .map(RecordWrapperDto::getRecordId)
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(null);
return recordWrapperDtos
         .stream()
         .filter(c -> c.getRecordWrapperId() != null)
         .filter(c -> recordId.equals(c.getRecordId()))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The sad part is to stream twice to get the non-null recordWrapperId first.

Comment: @Tunaki but the update of recordId is only useful if it is `null`, which it is not since it is set first.

Comment: @Tunaki Right but in the original code it is set on each loop. Your setting it only once and outside the loop.

Comment: Correct. It was intended for @njzk2.

Comment: @Tunaki `recordId.equals(c.getRecordId())` -> `recordId = c.getRecordId()` is useless (unless `getRecordId` is not idempotent, which would suck)

Comment: @Tunaki you are saying that you should call `recordId = rwDto.getRecordId()` if `recordId.equals(rwDto.getRecordId())`. There is a good chance it is not really necessary.

Comment: Mine is not to question why, but to fix someone else's code. ;-) Sonar really hates it.

Comment: @user447607 can we agree that all the objects in the result list will have the same `recordId`? since you set it if it is null (first iteration) and then you set it to the value *it was just compared to*, I don't see how it can change from an iteration to the other.

Comment: One of those values in the comparision is from a previous loop which is why we are having headaches. It's what Tunaki was getting at. You apparently can't maintain any state between loops.

Comment: OIC, answer has been updated. I will accept if you mention something about there being no means for transferring state between loops.

Comment: The first stream checks whether `getRecordWrapperId()` is non-`null` but lacks the `map(RecordWrapperDto::getRecordId)` step, hence its first item is an instance of `RecordWrapperDto`, not an id. Besides that, the original logic is not as simple, unfortunately. As long as `getRecordId()` returns `null`, the loop behaves differently (actually performing `add(rwDto)`) than after encountering the first non-`null` id (it compares the id for subsequent elements only).

Comment: @Holger you are absolutely right. I assumed the `getRecordId` would not return null. It seemed wrong to consider the test to null was both to initialize `recordId` and to grab all that have a null recordId prior to the first non-null recordId.

Comment: @user447607 I assume you mean the fact that lambdas (and anonymous classes) can only access final variables from a method context, hence making it impossible to update the value a lambda uses dynamically. There are ways around that, such as using an AtomicLong

Comment: @njzk2 I don't understand why you find the need to stream twice to be sad.  Your code is very clear.  While you had to write `stream` twice, I only had to read your code once to understand exactly what it was doing.  OP's code, while only having one loop, took much longer to read.

Comment: @njzk2 ...an Atomic? That makes sense, I suppose. How would you pass the reference around though?

Comment: @user447607 the AtomicLong can be set a long value, and you can get it from it. It can still be final, since the AtomicLong object itself does not change. Just declare it before your streaming expression

Comment: Just tried that. It has to be settable to null during the course of the loop, ...except it's final and initial value of an AtomicInteger is 0. The setter takes a primitive long instead of an object Long() and it's the same with the constructor, so theirs no way to make it null. Might work better using an AtomicReference and NullObject pattern.

Comment: @user447607 indeed. AtomicReference would certainly be more adequate than AtomicLong. (And NullObject more self-explanatory)